# Qu'est-ce que c'est, le piano bastringue?

Tags: terminologie, musique

Le piano bastringue est-il une sorte de musique ou une sorte d'instrument de musique? S'il s'agit de musique, quelle sorte de musique s'agit-il? Je suis un peu confus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'après l'[article piano sur wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano) le piano bastringue est simplement [une technique d'accord](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano#Technique_d.27accord) :

> Sur un piano, la plupart des notes sont produites par plusieurs cordes
>   vibrant en sympathie. Cela fait que si deux de ces cordes produisent
>   une fréquence différente même légèrement, la sonorité devient
>   désagréable ; cet effet peut cependant être recherché pour le piano «
>   bastringue ».

Cela dit, rien ne précise si c'est ou non un instrument spécial.

Grâce à l'article [General MIDI](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) (une norme à laquelle je ne comprends rien), on apprend que le terme anglais de piano bastringue est **Honky-Tonk Piano**.

Et si on fait une recherche sur Honki-Tonk Piano, on trouve l'article [Tack piano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tack_piano), malheureusement plutôt succinct.

On peut encore faire une recherche de tack piano sur le wikimedia commons, et on trouve [un piano](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hammond_RT-3_&_Challen_piano,_Abbey_Road_Studios,_80th_Anniversary,_March_9,_2012.jpg) entreposé aux studios d'ABBEY ROAD, piano supposé avoir un son de *tack piano*.

[image: tack piano]

Donc, si je résume, ça à l'air d'être une façon d'accorder un piano, plus qu'un instrument spécial.

Comment: Merci Istao. Votre réponse est très utile. Dans un tack piano, des clous sont attachés aux marteau produisant un son avec la percussion plus forte.

Answer (score 2):

Il semblerait que ça soit un type de piano qui posséderait une troisième pédale permettant de donner un son qui ressemble à une percussion d'où le nom de bastringue.

**Source:** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WG1RakZeH0

Il n'y a ceci dit, effectivement, peu d'infos sur le net (en tout cas je n'ai pas trouvé grand chose).

**EDIT:** Et étant un instrument particulier, peut-être qu'il a un style qui l'accompagne ? Désolé, je ne suis pas pro.